# How to setup sockets on docker-compose version 2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using:

- ubuntu:14.04
- docker 1.10.3
- docker-compose 1.6.2

I can set up sockets on docker-compose version 1 by doing something like this:

```
 container_name_1:
 container_name: container_1
 image: <- image -> 
 volumes:
  - "/root:/home/app"
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  - "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro"
  - "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1:ro"
  - "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.1.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.1.0:ro"

container_name_2:
 container_name: container_2
 image: <- image -> 
 volumes:
  - "/root:/home/app"
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
  - "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro"
  - "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1:ro"
  - "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.1.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.1.0:ro"
```

However when I try in the version 2 syntax it doesn't work:

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3000:3306"
    container_name: mysql_container
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<-- password -->
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=<-- database -->
    volumes_from:
      - data
  data:
    image: ubuntu
    container_name: data_container_name
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
  do_something:
    image: <-- image -->
    container_name: action_container
    volumes_from:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro
      - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1:ro
      - /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.1.0:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapparmor.so.1.1.0:ro
    depends_on:
      - data
      - mysql
volumes:
  data_container_name:
    driver: local
```

The error I get is:

```
ERROR: Unknown volumes_from type '/usr/bin/docker' in '/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro'
```

I have a docker executable at that location and it works when using the version 1 format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`volumes_from` syntax in version 2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-from) mentions:

```
volumes_from:
 - service_name
 - service_name:ro
 - container:container_name
 - container:container_name:rw
```

`/usr/bin/docker` is neither a container or a service name.

```
volumes_from:
  - data:/var/lib/mysql                 <=== works
  - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker:ro  <=== won't work
```

You would need to [use `volumes:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver) in order to mount *paths*:

```
- /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll let you know how it goes after the changes!

Comment: We are realizing that opening sockets might not be the best thing for us and are looking into the Docker Remote API instead.  Referencing volumes_from through your explanation does work, it will take more to set up sockets though, and that is a different question entirely.